# How to disable 10.7 window restoration feature?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, osx-lion

I have an older application that consistently crashes on 10.7. It appears to be related to the new window restoration feature. Is there a way to disable this behavior via Info.plist or a preference? How about in ObjC code?

Comment: I found the API calls. Is the default behavior to disable both of these? 
`@interface NSWindow (LionSDKDeclarations)
- (void)toggleFullScreen:(id)sender;
- (void)setRestorable:(BOOL)flag;
@end`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can disable it by modifying a default like this when your application starts up.

```
 defaults write applicationidentifier NSQuitAlwaysKeepsWindows -bool false
```

Where `applicationidentifier` is the identifier of your application. For example, `com.Apple.TextEdit` for TextEdit.

Of course, the real thing to do is fix your application to support this feature properly.

Answer (score 1):

You can toggle window restoration in Interface Builder, too. Just go to the Attributes Inspector.